# How can I force Deno to download latest version of a dependency?

Tags: node.js, deno

I want to use the latest version of https://deno.land/std/http/server.ts, but it's still using an old cached version when I run my server.

In node.js I would use:

```
npm i package@latest
```

What's the equivalent in Deno?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In order to reload a module or all modules you have to use: [`--reload`](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/denoland/deno/master/std/manual.md#reload-specific-modules)

For that module specifically:

```
deno run --reload=https://deno.land/std/http/server.ts index.js
```

or just use `--reload` without any value to reload all modules:

```
deno run --reload index.js
```

You can even select a couple of modules if you pass comma separated modules to `--reload`

```
deno run --reload=module1,moduleN index.js
```

Or reload all `std` modules

```
deno run --reload=https://deno.land/std index.js
```

You can use `deno cache` instead of `deno run` too. The former will just download the dependencies, while the former download & run the script.

---

Have in mind that some packages if not most use the version in the URL, so in case you want to update you'll need to update your `import` to that specific URL.

Let's say you have:

```
import { serve } from 'https://deno.land/std@v0.36.0/http/server.ts'
```

And now you want to use `v0.41.0`, you'll need to update the code instead of using `--reload` since reload will download again `v0.36.0`

```
 import { serve } from 'https://deno.land/std@v0.41.0/http/server.ts'
```